# For consecutive files w/ prefixes "1_",…"56_", how do I increment the prefix when new files are randomly added and shift the original file placement?

Tags: javascript, filenames, batch-processing, file-rename, batch-rename

I have many folders I work with that have LOTs of consecutively placed files, and I number them with the prefixes "1_", "2_", "3_", and so on. Many times newer files end up being added in at random places which shifts the numbering, making it a time consuming to rename by hand.

For example:

1. 1_[Original file 1].jpg
2. **2_[NEW file 2].jpg**
3. 2_[Original file 2].jpg -->  shifts to become "3_..."
4. 3_[Original file 3].jpg --> shifts to become "4_..."
5. **4_[NEW file 4].jpg**  --> shifts to become "5_..."
6. 4_[Original file 4].jpg --> needs to become "6_..."
7. **5_[NEW file 5].jpg** --> needs to become "7_..."
8. 5_[Original file 5].jpg --> needs to become "8_..."
9. 6_[Original file 6].jpg --> needs to become "9_..."
10. 7_[Original file 7].jpg --> needs to become "10_..."
11. **8_[NEW file 8].jpg** --> needs to become "11_..."
12. 8_[Original file 8].jpg --> needs to become "12_..."

How could I write I javascript the would address this? Or are there already programs out there that can do this stuff?
I imagine the script would have to have to be built along the following pseudo code:

```
arrayOfFileNames = [];

For (i = 0; i <= arrayOfFileNames.length; i++)

string originalFile
\\needs to hold original file's regular expression for the prefix "$*_"

string newFile
\\holds the regular expression of the prefix for the new file

if(newFile == OriginalFile)
\\line to increment prefix
```

I have no idea how I could implement this, but it would save me a ridiculous amount of time of I could. How do I even go about using functions to pass and edit file names on my computer? (I have Windows 10)

Comment: You can't do this task with JavaScript. You can write a PowerShell script or Python script to do this task.

Comment: So how could I go about doing it with either of those?

Comment: @Shams Sure you can. Use windows script host, nodejs or something else.

Comment: @Bergi, ohh i forgot about nodejs, i thought he is asking for JS in html page. Thanks for correcting me :-)